# Working with Dates within cells in Google App Scripts

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an array that I would like to filter by using only dates AFTER a certain period (the 4th column in the array).  The startDate variable is the date within a cell that I would like to filter the array by.  I also want to filter out the blank cells in the 4th column.  I've tried a few different things, but the function is returning the entire array with JUST the blank columns filtered. Here's the latest Code I've tried.

```
function invPayable(){
   var overview = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Overview");

   var paymentLog = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1KkR4jE1c00WuQpPrexW8f9BIq5vxl0fWaUGxbeYERsE").getSheetByName("Payment Log");
   var paymentArr = paymentLog.getRange(3, 1,paymentLog.getLastRow(),paymentLog.getLastColumn()).getValues();
   var startDate = new Date(overview.getRange(3, 1).getValue());

   var pay1 = paymentArr.map(function(r){return [r[0],r[1],r[2],r[3]]})
      .filter(function(item){
      if(item[3]!=""){return true}
      if(item[3]>=startDate){return true}
      else{return false}
   });

 //execute
 overview.getRange(2, 18,pay1.length,4).setValues(pay1);
 overview.getRange(6,1).setValue(startDate);
}//Added by editor
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Issue:

```
if(item[3]!=""){return true}
if(item[3]>=startDate){return true}
```

Once the first `if` condition is satisfied(i.e., column 4 is not empty), the function  ends and returns `true`. The second `if` condition  is never  checked. Therefore,

> the function is returning the entire array with JUST the blank columns filtered.

#### Solution:

Check both conditions before ending the function.

#### Snippet:

```
if(item[3]!="" && item[3]>=startDate ){return true}
```

Comment: Hello!  this worked. Can't believe I missed this.  Thank you